# How to convert netmask to wildcard with netaddr python library?

Tags: python, networking, netmask

I want to convert **netmask** to **wildcard mask** with **netaddr** library

so the input is `netmask = 255.255.255.0` and the output is `wildcard = 0.0.0.255`

or the input is `netmask = 255.255.255.252` and the output is `wildcard = 0.0.0.3`

Comment: Combine a string split, int conversion and `xor 255`.

Comment: with netaddr libray or no?

Comment: Just subtract each octet from 255. There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) about the host mask (wildcard mask; there is a slight difference in that a host mask like a network mask must be contiguous bits, but a wildcard mask does not need to have contiguous bits) that explains how to calculate the host mask from the network mask.

Answer (score 0):

**netaddr** not support non-contiguous wildcard but **cisco-acl** can help to play with wildcard

```
from cisco_acl import AddressAg

address = AddressAg("0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0")
mask = address.subnet.split()[1]
wildmask = address.wildcard.split()[1]
print(mask)  # 255.255.255.0
print(wildmask)  # 0.0.0.255
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions wanting to use the `netaddr` library. Without an explanation, I don't think this answer answers the question.

Comment: Please avoid providing code-only answers without an explanation on why your code resolves the question. While the code may solve the problem, the answer is not useful in understanding why it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, all netmask octets are one of nine possible values "0", "255", "192", "224", "240", "248", "252", "254", or "255".  Given this, a simple solution is:

```
netmask.replace("0", "255").replace("128", "127").replace("192", "63").replace("224", "31").replace("240", "15").replace("248", "7").replace("252", "3").replace("254", "0").replace("255", "0")
```